# Killing a bash sh script

Tags: bash, terminal, curl, sh

I made an .sh file `load.sh` which has (almost) unlimited loop of curl requests. I run this as `$ bash load.sh`. Now it just keeps running the loop. I can't cancel its execution. It keeps running. I pressed `ctrl+c` to cancel but it starts again. I closed the terminal window. But in background script is still running. how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get the pid and kill the process. Its a beginner question

```
ps -ef | grep [l]oad.sh  # second column is the PID

kill <PID>
```